# String array value in a mysql WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string array value but I don't know how to use it in a sql statement.

I've tryied using **implode** but nothing happens.

this is my code:

```
$select_tbl=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname'");
while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_object($select_tbl)) {
    $r = $fetch->lessons;
    $i = explode(",",$r);
    foreach ( $i as $item ) {
        $string .= $item.',';
        echo $string;
    }
}


$_SESSION['library'] = $_GET['library'];
$_SESSION['lessonID'] = $_GET['lessonID'];
$_SESSION['department'] = $_GET['department'];
$dept = $_SESSION['dept'];
$library = $_SESSION['library'];

$checkID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["lessonID"]);
$checkdept = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["department"]);
$department = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['dept']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery 
        WHERE lessonID = '$checkID' AND departmentg='$checkdept' AND library='$library' AND titleGallery='$string'";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
```

I want to get the string array of the **foreach** statement in my code so that I can use it for the **WHERE** clause in my **SELECT** statement.

Comment: what is the output of $i

Comment: Side comment - don’t use `echo $string;` inside the `foreach()` loop as it will echo it `$i` number of times.

Comment: @blackbird Paradise Forest,Water Drop,pdf. But when I implement it on my sql statement, nothing happens.

Comment: Please mention $r & $i values bcz we don`t know the input coming from = $fetch->lessons;

Comment: @blackbird I just want to see if it really echo out the value from my database. But thank you for your advice sir, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @GavinBautista if you want to check the output from the database you can use ChromePhp tool.

Comment: @blackbird the value of those variables are from the database sir. I want to to get the values from my users table so that I can reflect it to the gallery table.

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm just a beginner. Can you give me a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are doing string to array & array to string conversion:

```
$r = $fetch->lessons; //string
$i = explode(",",$r); //array
foreach ( $i as $item ) { //array parsing
  $string .= $item.','; //string
}
```

instead of that you can use:

```
//declare string array before while loop
$string_array = array();
$string_array = array_merge($string_array,explode(',',$fetch->lessons)); //Final Array
```

You can use in sql query like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE lessonID = '$checkID' AND departmentg='$checkdept' AND library='$library' AND titleGallery IN (".implode(',',$string_array).")";
```

Comment: This is the error handler sir: if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {echo "SQL statement failed!";}

Comment: SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE lessonID = '1' AND departmentg='opex' AND library='video' AND titleGallery IN (Paradise Forest,Water Drop,pdf,)

Comment: This error is coming bcz of the space between the string & also bcz of the last ',' to remove that change my code.. where i created on string_array & merging that array with new lessons & finally imploding into the $sql. Bcz of implode every array index value converting to string...

Comment: I have an error sir, line 43 is "Declare $string_array = array();": Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$string_array' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\lesson1_1_user.php on line 43.

Comment: $string_array = array(); before the while loop & don`t use 'Declare' word

Comment: Thank you Sir! You're the best! I change the implode from your statement to a string sir, because the implode in your statement is for integers. That also fix my problem. Thank you so much for helping me patiently. You're the best!